# How to determine pidgin install path

Tags: pidgin

I'm trying to determine the install location of Pidgin so I can add it to my application startup.  I've looked at `top` but it doesn't show paths.  How can I find out where it's installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're asking how to find the location of the `pidgin` executable, and you have installed Pidgin normally, you should be able to do

```
which pidgin
```

If this doesn't find it, you could try

```
find / -name pidgin -executable -type f 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which pidgin` in console.

Answer (score 1):

The default application directory is /usr/bin. As Sergey said, you can also use `which <appName>`